# How to resolve Map issue?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Map in My Application. Everything is fine.

**Problem:**

I am calling Map Activity from two different According according to the Work Flow.

> Now What Happen, If i Open the Map Activity First Time working fine.

***`But`** If I Close the Map Activity and Reopen the Map Activity from the Another Activity, Map Activity **Freezes***  and I What I am facing is **`Map does not refresh`**

---

On other side, In Nexus 7 (4.4.3) work fine the same code.

> I do not understand, what happened in 4.0.4 device.

---

**DOES MAP USES CACHE ???** If Yes than we can release it by programaically.

Comment: does you able to get the zoom buttons...

Comment: I am point the Marker on the Map and their click PopUp some detail on that particular marker.... @vinayManeti

Comment: like you want to show markers on the map...

Comment: @vinayManeti  I said .. I have two different Activity and In both I want to display Map ... If I open First Activity , map loaded with markers ... work fine ... Now after this I open the second activity map does not reload with new data(marker) .. And map freez .... but in nexus work fine this thing.. May be you got my point or should I elaborte from another way >